# System.ExecutionEngineException Occurs in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8.1, local-storage, executionengineexception

H!!  I am Developing windows phone 8.1 application. which has functionality to import videos and export videos into my app. But after when I perform one or two operation in my app like importing or exporting videos it gives me error like `System.ExecutionEngineException occurred in Unknown Module.` I am importing and exporting videos from knownfolders to my localfolder and code for that is not wrong. I am able to import or export videos one or two time but after error occurs. please give me right solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is going to be tough to get help without any code or more information.

Comment: I am also struggeling with an ExecutionEngineException in a similar scenario right now. Maybe you could provide a code sample? This might help both of us!

Comment: Run your app without debug. it was helped me.

Comment: If the exception doesn't show up without debugger attached, it seems to be a case of internal VS error so you see a ghost exception that is created but should not be activated with no actual reason to: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/08/10/why-do-i-see-executionengineexception-stackoverflowexception-and-outofmemoryexception-on-the-heap-when-debugging-net-applications/